# ORACLE : Create table - Missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I do not understand why my function raises this error :

```
CREATE TABLE "CVAULTIMPORTLOG" (
   "ID"       RAW(16) DEFAULT sys_guid(),
   "DATE"     TIMESTAMP(6),
   "TYPE"     NUMBER,
   "CODE"     NUMBER,
   "MESSAGE"  VARCHAR2(500 BYTE),
   CONSTRAINT "PK_CVAULTIMPORTLOG" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);
```

I use SQL Developer, thanks !

Comment: Your error is elsewhere.  Here is a SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5d20.

Comment: Why do you refer to a function in the question? Are you trying to create this from inside a function, or is that just a mistake? Are you running this as a statement or as a script, and are there other statements in your worksheet?

Comment: It is just a mistake. What I called a function it is the script to create the table. I am running it as a script.

Comment: Then what else is in the script/worksheet - are you sure the error is coming from this statement?

Comment: @Majestic Execute the content of the script, and see the error comes from which line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no issues creating the table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE "CVAULTIMPORTLOG"
  2    (
  3      "ID" RAW(16) DEFAULT sys_guid(),
  4      "DATE"    TIMESTAMP(6),
  5      "TYPE"    NUMBER,
  6      "CODE"    NUMBER,
  7      "MESSAGE" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE),
  8      CONSTRAINT "PK_CVAULTIMPORTLOG" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  9    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

On a side note, be aware of the **double-quotation marks**. A **quoted identifier** begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.

Comment: Hum... I dont get it...
Now I have an error because the name is already used by an existing object, but I can not see the table in the explorer...

Comment: @Majestic Post the output of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME='CVAULTIMPORTLOG';`

Comment: Error starting line 10 of the command :
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME="CVAULTIMPORTLOG"
Error starting line : column 10 , raw: 52
Rapport :
Erreur SQL : ORA-00904: "CVAULTIMPORTLOG" : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @Majestic Don't use double-quotes, you need single-quotes. Copy paste my query in the comment. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME='CVAULTIMPORTLOG';`

Comment: @KevinEsche missing right parenthesis error doesn't have to do anything with user privileges. Had that been an issue, the error would be table/view doesn't exist.

Comment: Here we go :
COUNT(*)               
---------------------- 
1

Comment: @Majestic It means the table was successfully created. Or at least an object of that name already exists. Check `SELECT OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, OWNER FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME='CVAULTIMPORTLOG';`

Comment: OBJECT_NAME                                                                                                                      OBJECT_TYPE         
---------------------
CVAULTIMPORTLOG                                                                                                                  TABLE   

Can not get the Owner, an error occurs.

Comment: @Majestic - `user_objects` doesn't have owner; you can get that from `all_objects`, but it is clearly yours. Do you just need to refresh the explorer view to see it? It still sounds like the table was created the first time and the error was from something else - even an earlier attempt with a typo you corrected; maybe you have feedback off and that confused you. We can't see what you see, unfortunately.

Comment: Oops, my bad. USER_OBJECTS doesn't have owner, as you are executing as the owner itself, so no need of it. Anyway, so you have the table already created. As Alex mentioned, did you refresh the explorer? We only know what you tell us, so you need to tell the completely story.

Comment: @Majestic Please mark it as answered if it resolved your problem. Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/tour, would help you in future about this site.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys do not blame me...
As Alex Poole just said it, I forgot to refresh the explorer view...
Too much computer science for today...

Anyways, thank all of you for you help !
Have a nice day !

Comment: A simple select would have been enough :-) You know, that command-line vs tool ;-)